# Bash function, return value and error handling

Tags: bash, error-handling

I am trying to wrap my head around Bash, and think I have gotten pretty far. What I really don't understand yet is the error handling...

I have the following script:

```
set -e
set -u

DOWNLOADED_ARTIFACT=$(downloadApplication "$WEB_GROUP")
if [[ $? != 0 ]]; then
  exit 1
fi
```

Even though the downloadApplication function fails (my expected result now), the script does NOT fail. I can't really figure out how to check this when capturing the output into a variable. If I don't put it back into a variable it works and fails as expected:

```
downloadApplication "$WEB_GROUP"
if [[ $? != 0 ]]; then
  exit 1
fi
```

What are my options? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

```
DOWNLOADED_ARTIFACT=$(downloadApplication "$WEB_GROUP" || echo "SomeErrorString")
if [ $DOWNLOADED_ARTIFACT == "SomeErrorString" ]; then
  exit 1
fi
```

That means "if `downloadApplication` is not successful, then echo `SomeErrorString`" (so your `DOWNLOADED_ARTIFACT` will be set to `SomeErrorString`. Then you can compare against that value.

Answer (score 0):

The command `DOWNLOADED_ARTIFACT=$(downloadApplication "$WEB_GROUP")` will always suceed, because what matters for `$?` is the assignment to the variable, which is (nearly) guaranteed to succeed, either with the assignment of `0` or `1` to `DOWNLOADED_ARTIFACT`.

Comment: I don't think this is true: `var=$(sh -c 'exit 1'); echo $?` outputs `1`. `$?` is the exit status of the last command, and variable assignment is not a command.

Answer (score 0):

Your error handling works fine for me. In fact, with `set -e` the script exits on the execute-and-assign line because the result isn't checked. Are you sure that `downloadApplication` exits with the correct exit code? Try executing `downloadApplication "$WEB_GROUP"; echo $?` directly on the command line.

By the way, you can check the return code and capture the output in a single statement:

```
if ! DOWNLOADED_ARTIFACT=$(downloadApplication "$WEB_GROUP"); then
    echo "Download failed"
    exit 1
fi

do_something $DOWNLOADED_ARTIFACT
```